# About IText AcroFields

Tags: itext

I am trying to generate pdf from template using iText. I've set value in AcroFields. when I opening output file, there is nothing on it.Is there anyone who had same problem before? .

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destPath);
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(templatePath);  
PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(reader, fos);
AcroFields form = stamp.getAcroFields();
form.setField("parttype", "1dafd");
stamp.setFormFlattening(true); 
stamp.close(); 
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

Comment: I'm voting to close your question because it is unclear. You say that you are trying to *generate* a PDF file. However, your code shows that you are trying to *manipulate* an existing PDF file. You say that there is nothing inside the output file. What does that mean? Is the existing content gone? Or is `1dafd` not showing? If the latter: are you sure there is a field named `parttype` in the PDF? Maybe the field has a longer name. Has anyone had the same problem? Yes, when trying to fill a form without a field named `parttype`. No, the problem doesn't occur when there is such a field.

Comment: Taylor - to help @Bruno, me, and others to sensibly respond to your question, you could simply share the PDF in question, e.g. via some public drop box or google drive share for which you post the URL here.